# Efficient way of making data contiguous to transfer it among nodes

Tags: c++, mpi, contiguous

```
struct Face
{
    // Matrixd is 1D representation of 2D matrix
    std::array < Matrixd<5,5>, 2 > M;
};

std::vector <Face> face;
```

I have a distributed for-loop among nodes. After all nodes finish working on their elements I would like to transfer corresponding elements among nodes. But AFAIK to use `MPI_Allgatherv` the data should be contiguous. First of all, I switched to 1D representation of 2D matrices (I was using [][] notation before). Now I want to make `face.M` to be contiguous. I am thinking to copy all elements of say, M[0] to an `std::array` an transfer that among nodes. Is this way efficient? To give an idea of number of data I work with, if I have 20k cells, at maximum I have 20k*3=60k faces. I might have a million of cells, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A true 2D array in C/C++, e.g. `int foo[5][5]` is already contiguous in memory; it's basically just syntactic sugar for `int foo[25]` where accesses like `foo[3][2]` implicitly look up `foo[3*5 + 2]` in the flat equivalent. Switching to a `Matrixd` defined in a single dimension won't change the actual memory layout.

`std::array` is (mostly) just a wrapper for C-style arrays as well; with no virtual members, and compile time defined size with no internal pointers (just the raw array), it's also going to be contiguous. I strongly suspect if you checked the assembly produced, you'd find that the `array` of `Matrixd`s is already contiguous.

In short, I don't think you need to change anything; you're already contiguous, so MPI should be fine.

Comment: `M` is contiguous but I would like to make number of `face.M`s to be contiguous to send/receive as a bunch instead of doing that one by one.

Comment: At least as of C++03, [`std::vector` is also guaranteed to be contiguous](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector): "The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets on regular pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an element of an array." So the only reason the `M`s wouldn't be contiguous is if the structure required padding for alignment related reasons (which seems unlikely given the design).

Comment: @Shibli: Since the `std::vector` stores the elements in line, you've got contiguous `vector` of contiguous `struct` of contiguous `array` of contiguous `Matrixd`. You're already golden (just don't change the vector's size or call `reserve` when you're using the values in it, or a reallocation could invalidate pointers into the `vector`). You'd only lose contiguous behavior if the `vector` stored `Face*` or `Face&` instead of actual `Face`.

Comment: So when I use say `MPI_Send,` if I give pointer to `face[0].M[0][0][0]` as a parameter and give number of elements as another parameter etc., will the function work fine?

Comment: @Shibli: Again, alignment/padding issues could occur, so you need to compute the number of bytes to transfer in terms of the compile time calculated size of a single `Face`, but if you pass `&face[0].M[0][0][0]` and a length of `numelements * sizeof(face[0])` or whatever, that should take care of that. Heck, passing `&face[0]` should work, no need for `.M[0][0][0]`.

Comment: I don't resize `face` later so if understood correctly passing `face[0].M` should suffice. Also, if struct `Face` has more members and `M` is not the first one then passing `&face[0]` would NOT work, right?

Comment: If `Face` is just the `std::array` as described (no virtual methods or other members), then `&face[0]` and `&face[0].M` are equivalent. If it has other members, or has virtual methods, then no, it won't work.